# Change execution thread of the current method

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

With tasks it is possible to do something like this:

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    // [A] Here I am in the caller thread

    await OtherMethod().ConfigureAwait( false );

    // [B] Here I am in some other thread
}

private async Task OtherMethod()
{
    // Something here
}
```

Where in points [A] and [B] you can be in different threads. Is it possible to do something similar withous async and await keywords with choosing the thread, it will swtitch to? Like so:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // [A] Here I am in the caller thread

    ChangeThread();

    // [B] Here I am in some other thread
}

private void ChangeThread()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(???);
    // ???
}
```

I know this is possible with delegates, but is is possible to switch thread inside of a method, with possibly changing current thread back when method ends? If not, is it possible to craft something using async/await that can change thread, but I am in control of to which thread it will switch to (like UI thread using Control.Invoke)?

Comment: What are you trying to do and *why*? Why do you want to "change thread" (there is no such thing)? Have you encountered a problem and think that "changing threads" is the solution? What does "which thread" mean? Why not use the thread pool or simply use `Task.Run`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's asked by pure curiosity and do not represent a real life problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do in cases where I need to change execution context and then go back to original context is :

```
public async void RunWorkerAsync()
    {
        var result = await RetriveDataAsync();
    }


 public Task<Object<TItem>> RetriveResultsAsync()
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ct = tokenSource.Token;


        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<Object<TItem>>();

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // [B] Here I am in some other thread
            while (!ConditionToStop)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    tokenSource.Cancel();
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }
        }, ct).ContinueWith(taskCont =>
        {

            if (resultedData != null)
            {
                source.SetResult(resultedData);
            }
        }, ct);


        bool taskCompleted = task.Wait(2000, ct);
        if (!taskCompleted)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        return source.Task;
    }
```

In case you want to execute all in one task with no results just pass the data and remove the taskCompleted part and rely only in the Condition to stop. Al your code will run on another thread and after in is completed execution will return to your calling thread. If something simple with no returns is what you need just use

```
Task.Run(Action() => ExecuteSomething);
```

within the method.

Comment: This is not really an answer to my question. You are just calling delegate on another thread (Task.Run) and, what is worse, cannot choose the Thread, it will run on. Instead, it will run on the Thread Pool thread.